# disadvantage change max.poll.records to 1 & fetch.max.wait.ms to 50ms in consumer config, especially in production?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, messagebroker

I have microservices that send data to another microservices, that have 2 API [ health check API and Send data API].
Flow of application is health check API hit destination server frequently to make sure server alive then data can be sent. if not, consumer stopped which is make data cannot be sent.
In Existing application , consumer stopped only if destination server down. After run some testing, there are lot of failed data that cannot sent. After some investigation, i found it because consumer config max.poll.records using default value (500).
To solve this problem, i also want to make consumer stopped if data failed to sent. To make that happen, i change config max.poll.records to 1 to make each message process and change config fetch.max.wait.ms to 50ms to make decrease consumer lag and problem solved.

My question is :

1. is there any disadvantage for that change [especially in production] ?
2. is there a possibility of duplicate data that will be consumed when i change concurrency to 6 ?

Thanks

Comment: `max.poll.interval.ms` only 50ms is a bit dangerous - any minor glitch (e.g. network) will cause a rebalance (and therefore duplicates). Setting `max.poll.records` to 1 will reduce performance, but that's ok if it is good enough for your needs. Concurrency has no bearing on these settings.

Comment: sorry @GaryRussell , my mistake.
i already change the question, i mistaken the config. i mean fetch.max.wait.ms not max.poll.interval.ms. thanks.
btw: can you give me advice for my problem, to reach my goal ?

Comment: best solution that i suggest is : change max.poll.records = 1 , change fetch.max.wait.ms = 50 , change setConcurrency = 6 (each partition have consumer)
any advice for this setting ?

Comment: `fetch.max.wait.ms` is meaningless without increasing `fetch.min.bytes` too. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.